# Setting X Frame Options on Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, web.xml

I need to configure X- Frame Options for my Angular.js Application which runs on Weblogic Server but I can,t seem to find an example. My preference would be to do it in web.xml file similar to this example for Tomcat :

[How do I set X-Frame-Options as response header in angularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40267011/how-do-i-set-x-frame-options-as-response-header-in-angularjs?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Tomcat and WebLogic are both j2ee application server, you can do the same as tomcat if you want

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did it the same way. Only problem I had was how to have a java class extending the filter class in an angular project. I solved this problem by making a seperate java project which contained this class , using this project as a dependency via maven in my angular project and then using the filter class in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

We also faced the same issue. One of the approach is suggested by 'user1107888'. You don't have to create another project explicitly

the other approach is,

1. Update the web.xml with the filter details.
2. Add the tomcat and its dependent jars as a part of the external jars OR add it to the build script of the war file (if you are not using maven or gradle) OR directly add it to the classpath of weblogic classpath.
3. In case you are using maven/gradle for your build, add them as dependency.

Hope this helps.